# Use netcat to listen on a port and send output from a command when a client connects

Tags: linux, networking, tcp, netcat

I have a Raspberry Pi (Debian Linux) connected to my LAN that can read data from some connected devices and output it to STDOUT.

Let's say the program is run on "Server" and I want to serve the output of the script `/usr/bin/data` to port 1234.

I want any client to pull the output of that script by connecting to that port, using something like

`nc Server 1234 > ServerData.txt`

I want the server to stay alive, run the script for each connection, serve the data and then close the connection to the client.  Server needs stay alive and wait for the next connection.

What is the netcat command to run on Server???

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One of the more advanced versions of netcat will be required. You can use `ncat` or `socat`:

***Server Side***

When client connects, execute the executable program `/usr/bin/data` and send program output to client.

**NCAT Method**:

```
$ ncat -l 1234 -c '/usr/bin/data' --keep-open
```

**SOCAT Method**

```
$ socat -U TCP-LISTEN:5403,fork EXEC:'/usr/bin/data',stderr,pty,echo=0
```

***Client Side***:

Connect to the server, and receive output from server.

**NCAT Method to File**

```
$ ncat Server 1234 | tee ServerData.txt
```

**NC (netcat) Method to stdout**

```
$ </dev/null nc <Server.ip> 5403 > /dev/stdout
```

*to save to a file replace /dev/stdout with a file name*

**WGET Method to File**

```
$ wget -q <Server.ip>:5403 -O myfile.txt
```

*to print results replace myfile.txt with /dev/stdout*

Comment: Looks fine, except the OP wants to execute `/usr/bin/data`, not send it. I think it should be `-c /usr/bin/data` or `-e /usr/bin/data`.

Comment: Use ncat developed by nmap project, it is more powerful than old nc.

Comment: @Joshua Besneatte sure